# can you change the BIOS on old HP laptop?

Tags: bios, dualboot

### i have a old HP laptop with 2 OS's and was wanting to try to change the BIOS to something neater and has dual-boot tools.

My questions are:

1. is it even possible to change the BIOS on laptops?
2. is there a BIOS anyone can recommend for easy dual-booting?

(P.S. the laptop is an HP 15-f024wm Notebook)

Comment: If any BIOS update is available you'll find at your product's page at HP's website.

Comment: @ChanganAuto what im wanting to know is if it is possible to *change* the BIOS entirely?

Comment: Which problem at you trying to solve, exactly? This looks like a X-Y problem and, needless to say, if you're asking such question thenj you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto the one on the top of my list is the not having to press 5 button to change the os. (also for some reason if i dont enter the boot device options to choose what os it just boots into bash)

Comment: So, a X-Y problem. The answer just posted gives the general idea. You may want to ask about the actual problem - with details about what happens, OSes, how they were installed in what drives, etc. - than what you think is a solution when it obviously isn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BIOS-es are not interchangeable.  They must be custom designed for the hardware of the system. As for dual-booting, the BIOS should have nothing to do with it. Dual boot relies on the MBR. The exception is the `secure boot` needs to be disabled if it exists in order to dual boot in most scenarios.

Comment: **No, in most if not ALL scenarios Secure Boot should be enabled**. Any Linux distro supports UEFI and consequently Secure Boot since more than a decade ago. And no, also since more than a decade ago, ANY boot is - should be - in UEFI mode so it definitely doesn't rely on "MBR".